# Trying to total price with checkbox loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is when a checkbox is clicked it's data-price should be added to the total variable and then this variable should be shown in the total price text box, however, it currently doesn't update the value when a checkbox is clicked.

Here is an interactive example of how it currently works/looks:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
const total = document.getElementsByName[0]('total');
document.getElementById("bookingForm").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.name === "event[]") {
    let total = 0;
    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]')].forEach(function(box) {
      if (box.checked) {
        total += +box.dataset.price;
      } //if
    })
    document.querySelector("[name=total]").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
 <section id="bookEvents">
  <h2>Select Events</h2>

 <div class='item'>
    <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
             <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
             <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
         </div>
 <div class='item'>
    <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
             <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
             <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
         </div>
      <section id="Cost">
   <h2>Total Price</h2>
   Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
  </section>
            
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book"></p>
  </section>
 </form>
```

Comment: Try with `const total = document.getElementsByName('total')[0]` other way around, you have `document.getElementsByName[0]('total')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Input` elements you should use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
const form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
const total = document.getElementsByName('total')[0];
document.getElementById("bookingForm").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.name === "event[]") {
    let total = 0;
    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]')].forEach(function(box) {
      if (box.checked) {
        total += +box.dataset.price;
      } //if
    })
    document.querySelector("[name=total]").value = total.toFixed(2);
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="bookEvents">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>

    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
    </section>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book"></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

PS: You have a typo at `line# 2` where `document.getElementsByName[0]('total');` should actually be  `document.getElementsByName('total')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
const total = document.getElementsByName('total');
var chksBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.chkEvent');

chksBoxes.forEach(function(chk) {
  chk.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var total = 0;
    chksBoxes.forEach(function(box) {
      if (box.checked)
        total += +box.dataset.price
    });
    document.querySelector("[name=total]").value = total.toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="bookEvents">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>

    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1 </span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>Price: 10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' class="chkEvent" name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2 </span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>Price: 5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' class="chkEvent" name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
    </section>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book"></p>
  </section>
</form>
```